# Computed Column Check Performance With Large Table Paging Query

Tags: sql, performance, t-sql, sql-server-2008, database-performance

I have this query to retrieve (see below, made short for simplicity) search data for jobs. We are dealing with about a million records.

```
Select ID
from
(
    Select ID,createDate
    ,SearchKeyMatchRank
    ,Row_Number() over(Order By createDate) As rowNumber
    from Jobs J
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        Select SearchKeyMatchRank=
        CASE WHEN @searchKey='""' THEN 0
        ELSE
        (Select IsNull([RANK],0) from FREETEXTTABLE(Jobs,title,@searchKey) Where [Key]=J.ID)*4
        +(Select IsNull([RANK],0) from FREETEXTTABLE(Jobs,description,@searchKey) Where [Key]=J.ID)*4
        +(
        select SUM(ISNULL(JS2.[Rank],0))
        from FREETEXTTABLE(JobSkills,skill,@searchKey) JS2
        Where JS2.[Key] in (Select ID from JobSkills Where jobId=J.Id)
        )*2
        END
    ) SMR
    Where
    SearchKeyMatchRank>0 --simplified here
) T2
where
rowNumber>=CASE WHEN @startIndex>0 AND @endIndex>0 THEN @startIndex ELSE rowNumber END
AND rowNumber<=CASE WHEN @startIndex>0 AND @endIndex>0 THEN @endIndex ELSE rowNumber END
```

**NOTES:**

I cannot use a regular join since I would need to find weighted ranks by passing the jobId to REETEXTTABLE.

**PROBLEM:**

Its extremely slow.

Apparently the problem is comparing a computed column.

```
SearchKeyMatchRank>0
```

If I take off 
Where SearchKeyMatchRank>0 
it takes less then a second.

Anybody got an idea how we could improve this?

Answer (score 0):

> Anybody got an idea how we could improve this?

Change the column from a computed column to a "regular" column. Try it in your test environment and see if the performance improvement is the same.

Comment: we cannot change it to a regular column because we have to calculate the weighted ranks on the fly based on the search key.

Answer (score 0):

If the column uses a non-deterministic function, the approach we've taken is to define a normal column on the table and add an insert/update trigger to updated the value. In this way, there will be a slight hit when a dependent field is changed or a new record is added, but it will not impact on query performance as the column is a standard SQL column. It can also be indexed easily.

Comment: Your idea is great when you have columns you can apply static computations. Unfortunately in this case we would not be able to do the same since we wont know the search key ahead of time until user enters it.